# Error while trying to send an email attachment

Tags: python

I am trying to send an email with both text and attachment and running into below error?

Removing the following block am able to send email but can't send the attachment, can anyone provide guidance on how to fix it?

```
   f = file(attachment_file_path )
    attachment = MIMEText(f.read())
    attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attachment_file_path)           
    msg.attach(attachment)
```

CODE:-

import os,smtplib
import subprocess,pprint,shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, call
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart

```
def sendEmail(type,data):
    global originalradar
    global gerriturl,email,username
    body = '''%s''' % (data)
    msg = MIMEMultipart(body)
    # sender = 'wifici@company.com'
    sender = 'username@company.com'
    receivers = ['username@company.com']
    #sendEmail(data)
    attachment_file_path = './wifi_projects/wifi-ci/.git/rebase-apply/patch'
    if type =='cherrypickfailure':
        msg['Subject'] = 'CHERRYPICK FAILED '

    msg['From'] = sender
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(receivers)
    try:
        mail = smtplib.SMTP('relay.company.com', 25)
        f = file(attachment_file_path )
        attachment = MIMEMultipart(f.read())
        attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=attachment_file_path)           
        msg.attach(attachment)
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body))
        mail.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
        print 'Email sent successfully'
    except Exception as e:
        print e

conflictedblocks = {'README': '<<<<<<< HEAD\nTRP\n=======\nTBD\n>>>>>>> <rdar://problem/42841519> Dummy radar\n'}
conflictedblocks_string = ""
for key,value in conflictedblocks.items():
    conflictedblocks_string +=  "<b><u>" +key + "</b></u>" +":" + "\n" + value + "\n"


sendEmail('cherrypickfailure',conflictedblocks_string)
```

Error:-

```
Cannot attach additional subparts to non-multipart/*
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `msg` object is of type `MIMEText`. You need a `MIMEMultipart` object in order to add attachments.

Add the message body as @stark suggests:

```
body = 'Your body content'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body))
```

Check [this great tutorial](http://naelshiab.com/tutorial-send-email-python/) where it talks about sending a mail with attachment.

Comment: I changed to `attachment = MIMEMultipart(f.read())` ,that doesn't help either

Comment: I changed to `msg = MIMEMultipart(body)` aswell and I get the error `string payload expected: <type 'list'>`

Comment: msg should be a list of two MIMEText

Comment: @dashboard ,@stark : I updated the question with my latest code after your suggestions it didnt help... can you please be more specific what exactly needs to be changed?

Comment: I updated  my code with `msg.attach(MIMEText(body))` and updated the question aswell,it didnt help..what am I missing?should I DELETE ANYTHING?

Comment: use `MIMEBase` for your attachment, not `MIMEMultipart`. And store the result of `f.read()` in a variable and set it as follows : `data = f.read();
attachment = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream');
attachment.set_payload(data);
msg.attach(attachment);` hope it's clear

Comment: still didnt help

Comment: It's most likely an issue about encoding the data as base64. I do recommend you to check the link in the updated answer please.

Comment: I hope someone can be very specific,you suggestions didnt help

Comment: That's upsetting. You see the updated link right ? http://naelshiab.com/tutorial-send-email-python/